# Angular filtering array within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I can't get my head around deep filtering using $filter or $grep.

I have an array of Store objects, each Store object contains an array of Orders:

**vm.Stores:**

```
[{
    Stores: [{
        Id: 1,
        Orders: [{
            Id: 11,
            Selected: true
        }, {
        {
            Id: 12,
            Selected: false
        }]
    }, {
        Id: 2,
        Orders: [{
            Id: 21,
            Selected: false
        }, {
        {
            Id: 22,
            Selected: true
        }]
    }],   
}]
```

I want an array of the Orders whose selected property is true:

**vm.selectedOrders:**

```
[{
    Id: 11,
    Selected: true
}, {
    Id: 22,
    Selected: true
}]
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
vm.selectedOrders = $filter('filter')(Stores.Orders, {'selected': true});
```

Obviously incorrect. Other methods I've tried are nested forEach loops, but I'm working with these orders a lot, so I need an efficient way to do it.

I've tried flattening the orders to their own array, but now I'm managing another object array, and it's not the object array that is used in my html, so it doesn't match.

The docs are  unhelpful. Filter is usable in so many ways, none of which seem to be right for me
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

and the parameter explanations make little sense

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

The example is

1. based on protractor
2. doesn't even contain a $filter('filter')!

And what's a comparator?

Comment: I don't have an angular project in front of me... but if i remember correctly you should be able to go `Stores[0].Orders`. If so, you could loop over stores and build up the selected orders. You would still be looping but only over each `Store`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Angular expert. However for your given structure you can't avoid nested loops, regardless if it is done with an Angular abstraction or via the language core - a straightforward solution might look like that ...

```
var
    Stores = [{
        Id: 1,
        Orders: [{
            Id: 11,
            Selected: true
        }, {
            Id: 12,
            Selected: false
        }]
    }, {
        Id: 2,
        Orders: [{
            Id: 21,
            Selected: false
        }, {
            Id: 22,
            Selected: true
        }]
    }],

    selectedOrders = Stores.reduce(function (collector, store) {

        collector = collector.concat(
            store.Orders.filter(function (order) {

                return order.Selected;

            })/*.map(function (order) {
                return {
                    storeId: store.Id,
                    orderId: order.Id
                };
            })*/
        );
        return collector;

    }, []);

console.log("selectedOrders : ", selectedOrders);
```

Comment: Oh. I thought the whole point of $filter and/or grep was that you could do it deep like this. Thx.

Comment: @DaveC426913 ... well, after all it still is JavaScript. A simple looking and handy abstraction via an API can't do any performance magic. It even adds more processes on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply using filter in view:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function() {
      var vm = this;

      vm.stores = [  
         {  
            "Id":1,
            "Orders":[  
               {  
                  "Id":11,
                  "Selected":true
               },
               {  
                  "Id":12,
                  "Selected":false
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "Id":2,
            "Orders":[  
               {  
                  "Id":21,
                  "Selected":false
               },
               {  
                  "Id":22,
                  "Selected":true
               }
            ]
         }
      ];
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat-start="store in main.stores" ng-bind="store.Id"></li>
    <ul ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="order in store.Orders | filter: { Selected: true }">
      <li ng-bind="'Id:' + order.Id"></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Except now my view does not reflect my model.

Comment: I didn't got you.. what you mean?